# Cannot properly sort through my arraylist

Tags: java, sorting, object, arraylist

so I'm trying to sort my arraylist of geometric objects in ascending order (by area). However, I'm running into an error

```
The method add(GeometricObject) in the type ArrayList<GeometricObject> is not applicable for the arguments (double)
```

in my code block

```
private static void selectionSort(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (i < list.size() - 1) {
                if (list.get(i).getArea() > list.get(i + 1).getArea()) {
                    double j = list.get(i).getArea();
                    list.remove(i);
                    list.add(i, list.get(i));
                    list.remove(i + 1);
                    list.add(j).getArea();
                    i = -1;
                }
            }
        }

     }
```

line

```
list.add(j).getArea();
```

Again, I'm just trying to sort them in order of their areas so i can later print the array. Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why are you adding a `double` to a `ArrayList<GeometricObject>`?

Comment: what exactly is the purpose of these lines: `list.add(i, list.get(i));` and `list.add(j).getArea();`? doesn't make a lot of sense to me

Comment: Ahh I didn't even catch myself *facepalm*. I think i may have solved the error by setting j equal to a GeometricObject and removing the getArea method and doing the same for the list.add(j) line. @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: Doesn't really make sense to me either lol, I thought i was just swapping around the areas when in reality I'm supposed to be swapping the entire objects list order. @Paul

Comment: Why don't you want to sort by using standard java Collections.sort and Comparator?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with what your talking about @rsutormin

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to do this instead

```
private static void selectionSort(ArrayList<GeometricObject> list) {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (i < list.size() - 1) {
                if (list.get(i).getArea() > list.get(i + 1).getArea()) {
                    GeometricObject j = list.get(i);
                    list.remove(i);
                    list.add(i, list.get(i));
                    list.remove(i + 1);
                    list.add(j);
                    i = -1;
                }
            }
        }

     }
```

I would consider change `j` to a more meaningful name. The issue occurred because of incomparable datatypes

Comment: This is exactly what i was aiming for. Thanks!

Comment: @RiFFRAFF you can make use of Collections.Sort() method to sort your ArrayList with Geometric objects rather than coding down selection sort and merge sort on your own. I have posted it here !
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33116198/how-to-pass-the-objects-of-two-arraylists-to-one-another-at-a-specified-index

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<GeometricObject>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(GeometricObject o1, GeometricObject o2) {
            if (o1.getGmtModified() != null && o2.getGmtModified() != null){
                if(o1. getArea() < o2. getArea()) {
                    return 1;
                }else if(o1. getArea() > o2. getArea()){
                    return -1;
                }else{
                    return 0;                        
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
    });
```